# Use variable as a map key

Tags: jsp, hashmap, key, el

I have something like this

```
<c:set var="x" value="a" />
```

Supposing I have a map like this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "1");
map.put("b", "2");
request.setAttribute("map", map);
```

I want to use variable `${x}` as map key in an EL expression, like this

```
${map.x}
```

(which is wrong) in order to print

```
1
```

(or 2) depending on the value of `${x}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the brace notation `[]` in order to use dynamic keys on a `Map`.

```
${map[x]}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)